# How to format the text input from Text Widget in Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In my tkinter program I'm collecting text from the user using `Text` widget, this is later printed on the screen using a `label` widget. Although I'm able to print it onto the screen, the text is all center aligned. Since what I'm collecting is a procedure for something it gets difficult to read, so I need it to be left aligned.

---

**This is my Procedure method** -
Once the procedure is collected it is stored into a dictionary

```
   def Procedure(self):

        textfield = Text(gui, height=30, width=82)
        textfield.place(x="20", y="100")

        procedure_label = LabelWidget(self.screen, "Procedure", "Courier", 40)
        procedure_label.Call().place(x="220", y="20")

        button_save = Button(gui, text="Next", padx="50", pady="20", bg="lightgrey",
                             command=partial(self.CheckPage, 4, procedure=textfield))
        button_save.place(x="250", y="600")
```

**This is how I'm printing my proceudre**

```
    proc_text_label = ""
    for i in fullDictProc:
        proc_text_label_temp = Label(root, text=i, wraplength=900)
        proc_text_label = proc_text_label_temp
    proc_text_label.config(font=("Courier", 12))
    proc_text_label.place(x=70, y=250)
```

---

### Here is a minimal reproducible code to demonstrate the problem

Run it and see the alignment of the text.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("700x700")


def printit(textfield):
    procedure_list = [textfield.get("1.0", "end-1c")]
    textfield.place_forget()
    proc_text_label = ""
    for i in procedure_list:
        proc_text_label_temp = Label(gui, text=i, wraplength=900)
        proc_text_label = proc_text_label_temp
    proc_text_label.config(font=("Courier", 12))
    proc_text_label.place(x=70, y=250)


textfield = Text(gui, height=30, width=82)
textfield.place(x="20", y="100")


button_save = Button(gui, text="Next", padx="50", pady="20", bg="lightgrey",
                     command=partial(printit, textfield))

button_save.place(x=500, y=600)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproducible example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you are looking for might be `justify`:

```
proc_text_label.config(justify='left')
```

Have a look at [The Tkinter Label Widget](https://web.archive.org/web/20200201190616/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is the [anchor](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_anchors.htm) parameter.
This is how it worked with your minimal example:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

gui = Tk()
gui.geometry("700x700")


def printit(textfield):
    procedure_list = [textfield.get("1.0", "end-1c")]
    textfield.place_forget()
    proc_text_label = ""
    for i in procedure_list:
        proc_text_label_temp = Label(gui, text=i, wraplength=900,
                                     anchor='w',
                                     bg='blue',
                                     width=50)
        proc_text_label = proc_text_label_temp
    proc_text_label.config(font=("Courier", 12))
    proc_text_label.place(x=70, y=250)


textfield = Text(gui, height=30, width=82)
textfield.place(x="20", y="100")


button_save = Button(gui, text="Next", padx="50", pady="20", bg="lightgrey",
                     command=partial(printit, textfield))

button_save.place(x=500, y=600)
gui.mainloop()
```

Comment: what does ```anchor``` and ```width``` do? and what parameter have you provided with anchor?

Comment: Also occasionally when I'm testing this code the alignment is disturbed, I'm not sure if it's because of long sentences or because of some limitation with ```anchor```

Comment: width sets the width of the label-box. anchor determines where in the box you text is going to sit. It takes in cardinal value ('n' for north, 'e' for east, 'w' for west, 's' for south, + combinations, see the link in the answer for more details